# Search for a full text sentence in new Android Studio LogCat

Tags: android-studio, logcat

This is driving me crazy. I wanna search for an exact match of a full sentence e.g

[image]

The new logcat in Android Studio Dolphin seems to reject spaces. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

After checking several guesses, found the solution with escaping spaces with `\`:

```
message:firebase\ analytics\ enabled
```